# Error "Use of unassigned local variable"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-web-api

The error is in "search, adapter.GetData(search, null, null, TextBox1.Text, null);"
which is a parameter, but already initialize the variable, in the other parameters does not mark error. why?

```
string search;
adapter.GetData(search, null, null, TextBox1.Text, null);
this.gridview.DataBind();
this.gridview.DataSource = adapter.GetData(search, null, null, TextBox1.Text,null);
```

Comment: you need to understand the difference between a variable that's in `Scope` vs one that is declared outside of the scope meaning if you declared it at the class level, it has a whole different meaning and one variable declared with the same name inside of a method takes precedence of the one declared at the class level or somewhere else in the application also you need to initialize the variable `search to string.Empty` or some other initial value the error message also tells you what's wrong.. `You need to assign the local variable a value initially`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a variable means assign it an initial value

```
string search; // not initialized, You define it's type and it's name. 
string search = "something"; //initialized
```

You can even set `null` value to search like `string search =null;`then compiler will not warn you because you are intentionally doing it.

if you need to search and bind returned search result to gridview

```
search = "set some value here";
//set data source
this.gridview.DataSource =adapter.GetData(search, null, null, TextBox1.Text, null);
//now bind the gridview 
this.gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is that when I assign a value to the search, I do not load the gridview.. i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

As it is right now, search is not a parameter, it is a local variable. That local variable does not have a value assigned to it, therefore the error. If you just want to test it, do something like

```
string search = "Any value you want to test";
```

Comment: Thank you very much served me, the problem is that when I assign a value to the search, I do not load the gridview.. i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

```
string search;
```

Is a declaration while

```
string search = "foo";
```

is an assignment.

Null is not a variable, and TextBox.Text1 has a value. You are getting that error because while the search variable is declared, it does not have a value assigned to it.

Comment: Thank you very much served me, the problem is that when I assign a value to the search, I do not load the gridview.. i don't know why

Comment: None, I do not mark error only when I click the "search" button to perform the search for a name I do not load the gridview, it does nothing